# Multiple columns in a data set into one column using R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
dF
    x     y     z     w
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

I would like to create a new column, which for each row stores the columns which are equal to TRUE, so for example row #1 would be c(x,z) (e.g. in character format).

In R would like to get following output

```
x     y     z     w          new
 
TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE     x,z
TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE      X,Y,Z
FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE      Z,W
```

I have tried one of the code from stack over flow , but I am getting the result in list form ,i.e: c(x,z)
but I want x,z
Please guide me on this
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use apply to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`), `paste` the `names` of elements (`toString` => `paste(..., collapse=", ")`)  after subsetting based on the logical vector

```
df1$new <- apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) toString(names(x)[x]))
df1
#      x     y    z     w     new
#1  TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE    x, z
#2  TRUE  TRUE TRUE FALSE x, y, z
#3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE    z, w
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we can reshape into 'long' format (`pivot_longer`) and do a group by (`row_number()`), `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
     group_by(rn) %>% 
     summarise(new = toString(name[value])) %>% 
     select(-rn) %>%
     bind_cols(df1, .)
```

---

Or another option is `c_across`

```
df1 %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(new = toString(names(.)[c_across(everything())]))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Rowwise: 
#  x     y     z     w     new    
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>  
#1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE x, z   
#2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE x, y, z
#3 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  z, w
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), y = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
), z = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), w = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be also reached with `paste0()` and `which()`:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(x=rep(T,3),
                 y=rep(F,3),
                 z=rep(T,3),
                 w=c(T,F,T))
#Apply
df$Var <- apply(df,1,function(x) paste0(names(x)[which(x==T)],collapse = ','))
```

Output:

```
     x     y    z     w   Var
1 TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE x,z,w
2 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE   x,z
3 TRUE FALSE TRUE  TRUE x,z,w
```